# Get number from user input and create users based on answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to take two parameters and based on these parameters, to create users with email.

`country = input("country shortcut")`.

The user will input country shortcut 'SG' as well as

`users = int(input("How much users would you like to create"))`

Number of users.

Taking those 2 parameters together and based on input number 2 it will create a user email such as:

> sg@example.com, sg1@example.com, sg2@example.com

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this problem? Could you post some relevant code other than the brief variable declarations you've added?

Comment: What do you mean by create users emails? Do you mean create instances of an object or just return some strings?

Comment: I'd like to return some strings just for my own use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with a little list comprehension:

```
country = 'sg'
users = 2

print(['{}{}@example.com'.format(country,i+1) for i in range(users)])
```

edit: rereading your question it seems that you also want a "base" email without a number, so the comprehension will look more like this:

```
['{}@example.com'.format(country)] + ['{}{}@example.com'.format(country,i+1) for i in range(users)]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, Thanks! now I'll be able to do the same for passwords as well!

Answer (score 0):

text formatting is pretty simple, i recommend the python decontamination.

for you problem

```
user amount = range(user_amount)
email_list =  ["{0}{1}@example.com".format(country_shortcut, code) for code in user_amount]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
country = input("country shortcut")
users = int(input("How much users would you like to create"))
emails = []
for x in range(users):
    emails.append('{}{}@example.com'.format(country, "" if (x==0) else x))
print(emails)
```

Output:
    `['sg@example.com', 'sg1@example.com', 'sg2@example.com']`